# Prevent SQL injection with dynamic queries

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-injection

So using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) always avoid injection when used in the where-clause parameters

```
select * from user where id = ? and group = ?
```

I need to set the column to select at runtime like

```
select ? from user where id = ? and group = ?
```

or even the column name in where-clause

```
select ? from user where ? = ?
```

But `PreparedStatement` don't support this. Any other who support this ?

**update**

- I change the title to get away the scope on PreparedStatement.
- I took PreparedStatement as an example for a library class that can handle "dynamic" queries
  avoid sql-injection on the where values.

My use case: I have a general purpose REST API to a(ny) database. *Users* may request

```
http://server/g/db100/users/300/phone
```

That is translated into

```
select phone from users where id = 300
```

`phone` could be any other column name (if column not exists the server response 404, etc). So I'm inetested to generate the query dynamically and wanted to know if there is a lib for this before going to do it myself.

Comment: prepared statement placeholders can represent only **VALUES**. They're not intended for sql keywords or table/field names. You'd have to build your statement dynamically. e.g. `sql = 'SELECT ' + fieldnamevar + ' FROM ' + tablenamevar + ' WHERE ' etc...`

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a stored procedure.

Comment: see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java#Dynamic_Queries_via_String_Concatenation

Comment: why are you needing variable column out of the select query?

Comment: notice that in the last example, the first ? would depend of the values from the second ?, so your query would need a complete analysis just to find out if it is valid. Another step would be necessary to discover if the content to be injected (actually are you injecting SQL code to avoid SQL injection?) is malicious, which is also very hard to find out without a human intervention.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that prepared statement's place-holder is for the column values not for table name.

Use String-concatenation for that like

```
String tablename="xyz";

String query= "select "+tablename+" from user where id = ? and group = ?";
```

Comment: `You cannot do that `, ok, I know this, I said `But PreparedStatement don't support this` and I was asking if someone knows one who can do this.

Comment: but the simple fact is you cannot do that then how comes the question of someone can do it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for your purposes (sample of building a dynamic query for a blog):

```
    $DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';port='.DBPORT.';dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);
    if (!$DB) {
        throw new Exception('Could not connect to database');
    }

    $sql = '';

    $select = array(); //which fields to select
    $join = array(); //any additional tables to join
    $where = array(); //'where' clause
    $params = array(); //parameters to add to PDO

    //regardless of parameters, select the id
    array_push($select, "posts.id");

    array_push($join, "blog_posts posts");

    array_push($where, "1=1");
    array_push($where, "published_date <= NOW()");

    //some sort of dynamic query - if we're specifying a search to filter by
    if (isset($search) && $search !== '') {
        $searchparts = explode(' ', $search);

        $searchsql = array();
        foreach($searchparts as $key=>$value) {
            array_push($searchsql, "(posts.title LIKE ? OR posts.content LIKE ?)");

            array_push($params, '%'.$value.'%');
            array_push($params, '%'.$value.'%');
        }

        array_push($where, '('.implode(' OR ', $searchsql).')');
    }

    //generate SQL query
    $sql .= 'SELECT '.implode(', ', $select).' FROM '.implode(' LEFT JOIN ', $join).' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where) . ' ORDER BY published DESC';

    $prepared = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $list = $prepared->execute($params);

    if ($list) {
        while ($row = $prepared->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            //do something with the data
        }
    }
```

Another option is to essentially whitelist your column names (Java):

```
if (column.equals("phone")) {
    sql += "phone";
} else if (column.equals("computer")) {
    sql += "computer";
}
```

This way you're not actually taking user input (though it doesn't actually matter because you've verified that `column` is exactly "`phone`"), and only building the SQL only on certain conditions, not just any input.

Comment: This question is tagged with [tag:java].

Comment: The question was asking about SQL injection, prepared statements, and dynamic queries.  Though the code isn't directly translatable, the functionality is.  I just had a PHP version of this on hand.